# Erro ao tentar instalar a biblioteca Gosu do ruby (OS X)

Tags: ruby, osx

Estou tentando instalar a biblioteca Gosu do ruby com o comando `sudo gem install gosu`, mas ele retorna a seguinte mensagem de erro: `ERROR:  Error installing gosu:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
The Gosu gem requires some libraries to be installed system-wide.
See the following site for a list:
https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-OS-X
creating Makefile
make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin14/ruby/config.h', needed by stb_vorbis.o.  Stop.
Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4/ext/gosu/gem_make.out`

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não precisa mais, problema resolvido!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta baixar essa GEM, que é pre-requisito:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Abraços ;)